# Display Background for MvxCollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to display a background Image for a MvxCollectionViewCell within an iPhone app built with Xamarin and MvvmCross. I am targeting iOS 6.0 and above. Below is code I am using. I am having a bit of trouble getting the background image to display. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Seems like it should be fairly straight forward. I created the cell in XCode. The cell is 100 X 100. It contains a single UIImageView, which is 90 X 72. The X and Y for the UIImageView are 5 and 8 respectively. I am also having trouble getting the Image to resize within the cell, but plan to post another question for this sometime soon.

```
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch.Views;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;

namespace DriveThroughSafari.Touch.Views.Pictures
{
public sealed partial class AnimalCutoutCell : MvxCollectionViewCell
{
    public static readonly UINib Nib = UINib.FromName ("AnimalCutoutCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString ("AnimalCutoutCell");

    private readonly MvxImageViewLoader _loader;

    public AnimalCutoutCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {

        MainImage = new UIImageView();
        _loader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => MainImage);

        BackgroundView = new UIImageView {Image = new UIImage("Images/photo-frame")};

        this.DelayBind(() =>
            {
                var set = this.CreateBindingSet<AnimalCutoutCell, AnimalDataViewModel>();
                set.Bind(_loader).To(animal => animal.ImageUrl);
                set.Apply();
            });
    }

    public static AnimalCutoutCell Create ()
    {
        return (AnimalCutoutCell)Nib.Instantiate (null, null) [0];
    }
  }
 }
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: It might be that when the nib loads then your background is overwritten - there's an override you can use - something like on nib loaded. Not online properly at the mo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried modifying the sample at: https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-11-KittenView_Collections

I changed the code to match your's - including this line in the constructor:

```
BackgroundView = new UIImageView {Image = new UIImage("MyImage.png")};
```

Where the image `MyImage.png` was included with build action `content` in the root of the Touch project.

This worked fine.

---

I suspect the first step here is to write some test code and to use a debugger - what does `var myImage = UIImage.FromFile("Images/photo-frame")` return? Is it a valid UIImage?

Comment: Stuart as always, I appreciate the awesome feedback!! It turns out that my image was way larger than UIImageView, and instead of resizing to fit inside the view, it just took up the entire cell. Creating an image with correct dimensions solved the issue. Any ideas on automagically resizing an image to fit into an UIImageView? As you can see above, I'm using MvxImageViewLoader to load the data.

Comment: new question for that sort of thing really (helps with search) - but I think you'll find the answer as easily as I will if you ... search for `UIImageView` and `scale` - I'm sure you'll find the answer...